# Hive - Metastore Connection on Startup

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, datanucleus

I have started having failures on hive command as follows:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/usr/local/someuser/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
... 12 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "rdbms". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "rdbms". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:528)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:788)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:310)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:339)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:248)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:223)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:475)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:523)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:397)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:356)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4944)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)
... 17 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "rdbms". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1217)
at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
... 46 more
```

Here is the hive-site

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
  <value>6</value>
  <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
  <value>7</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
  <value>/data/cloud/hive/logs/hive-${user.name}</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
  <value>/data/cloud/hive/logs/hive-${user.name}</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://somehost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>xx</value>
  <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>xx</value>
  <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
</property>


<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
  <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>


</configuration>
```

the version is 0.13.1

I have checked the lib directories of hadoop and hive both, as the logs complains about the classpath, but the jar datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar is already in the folder. I have tried to restart the metastore service as well but it didnt help at all.

any other point which might cause the error above? i was curious if there were any config changes prior to the errors, but it seems like no config updates either...

**EDIT**

Verbose logs: http://pastebin.com/jggaXF1X

Comment: How about looking in the LOG for the JDO provider? It tells you what jars it sees and whether there is indeed a StoreManager "rdbms" (aka datanucleus-rdbms) in the CLASSPATH

Comment: @NeilStockton tried to get something useful from there, but even with setting levels to ALL for datanucleus stuff, nothing was printed out

Comment: @NeilStockton it does creates the log file after starting up, but doesnt print anything into that file once i try to start it up... i have gone through http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/logging.html to double check if i was doing anything weird as well... but heh, still no clue

Comment: @NeilStockton finally got the verbose logs... couldnt paste directly here though... http://pastebin.com/jggaXF1X

Comment: You have no datanucleus-rdbms plugin in the accessible classpath, as the message advises. You would have a line "Registering bundle org.datanucleus.store.rdbms ... " if you had it accessible.

Comment: @NeilStockton, is it possible that disk/sector has outage or bad sector for the lib folder? i had some similar cases because of the physical disk issues for some other lib jars before... though not sure if this is a similar case... everything regarding the paths seem normal, and no change... as it has started happening out of sudden, just thinking if it is another physical disk outage

Comment: could be. all I know is that DataNucleus "core" needs to be able to find the plugin.xml and META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in the jar, so if that is inaccessible somehow then the plugin will not be recognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging the logs, as we were discussing with @NeilStockton in the comments, i have tried to redownload the related jar file, in the folder where the jar itself already exists... and it worked after the redownload...